# What is the Comonad typeclass in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, comonad

What is the Comonad typeclass in Haskell? As in Comonad from [Control.Comonad in the comonad package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad/1.1.1.1/doc/html/Control-Comonad.html) (explanations of any other packages that provide a Comonad typeclass are also welcome). I've vaguely heard about Comonad, but all I really know about it is that is provides `extract :: w a -> a`, sort of a parallel to Monad's `return :: a -> m a`.

Bonus points for noting "real life" uses of Comonad in "real" code.

Comment: I would really like to see what the difference between “co”  and normal is. I know what a monad is. So if I know what the “co” means, I can conclude myself, what a comonad is, and understand it deeply. Alexey Romanov’s answer did nothing in that aspect.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: "co" (loosely) means "flip the arrows". Here's a rough visual of that. Consider the monadic operations:
`return :: a ~> m a`, `flip bind :: (a ~> m b) -> (m a ~> m b)`.
Reverse the squiggly arrows and you get the comonadic operations:
`extract :: a <~ w a`, `extend :: (a <~ w b) -> (w a <~ w b)`
(`extract :: w a -> a`, `extend :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b`)

Comment: Thank you @Dan Burton… so while with a monad, you work on the “inside” (stuffing new and altered things in), with a comonad, you work on the “outside” (taking things out finally or just to alter them). Is that view correct? Because it certainly helps a lot with the deep understanding.

Comment: comonads can be used to model co-effects. Here is a great introduction to coeffects: http://tomasp.net/coeffects/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

These links may be helpful:

1. [Evaluating cellular automata is comonadic](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html). In particular, "whenever you see large datastructures pieced together from lots of small but similar computations there's a good chance that we're dealing with a comonad".
2. [Sequences, streams, and segments](http://conal.net/blog/posts/sequences-streams-and-segments)
3. [Comonads in everyday life](http://fmapfixreturn.wordpress.com/2008/07/09/comonads-in-everyday-life/)

Comment: +1 The first link was the one that really brought it together for me.

Comment: Link-only answer should at least contain a summary of the linked contents. Currently this answer isn't fit for being a good SO answer. Consider expanding it a bit, so that it can stand on its own without the linked articles.

Comment: _"whenever you see large datastructures pieced together from lots of small but similar computations there's a good chance that we're dealing with a comonad"_ .... So does that mean that fragment shaders are comonadic?

Comment: I found [this example](https://joneshf.github.io/programming/2015/12/31/Comonads-Monoids-and-Trees.html) of `extend` to be helpful.

Answer (score 25):

This doesn't fully answer my question, but I wanted to put some relevant information in answer format:

"co" (loosely) means "flip the arrows". Here's a rough visual of that.

Consider the monadic operations:

```
return :: a ~> m a
flip (>>=) :: (a ~> m b) -> (m a ~> m b)
```

Reverse the squiggly arrows and you get the comonadic operations:

```
extract :: a <~ w a
extend :: (a <~ w b) -> (w a <~ w b)
```

(Written with normal arrows)

```
extract :: w a -> a
extend :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
```

Notice how in this format, `return` is an arrow that just so happens to fit in the argument slot for `flip (>>=)`, and the same is true of `extract` and `extend`. Monad/comonad laws say that when you put `return` or `extract` into that slot, the result is the identity arrow. The laws are the same, "just with the arrows flipped". That's a super handwavey answer but hopefully it provides some insight.

Comment: Your answer goes well with avoiding the monad tutorial fallacy. Monads (and comonads) are just an interface. Although it would indeed be great to know how they were _intended_. As in: The idea behind them.