# Finding the Missing 'Reduce' Typeclass from Finger Tree Article

Tags: haskell, typeclass, finger-tree

Yesterday's [Wikibender](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wikibender) that started with [this stackoverflow qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428554/what-is-the-comonad-typeclass-in-haskell) on Comonads ended up at [MarkCC's](http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/about-markcc/) article on [Finger Trees](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2010/04/finger_trees_done_right_i_hope.php).

In the article he makes extensive use of the `Reduce` type class.  He writes about this typeclass as if it is a very common and frequently use library, but I cannot find it on hackage, nor can I find enough documentation to really understand the code.

Can someone help me understand what the `Reduce` typeclass is doing, how the `(-<)` and `(>-)` operators work, and what should tell me about the code in the article (copied below)?

---

**Code Listing from [Finger Trees Done Right (I hope)](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2010/04/finger_trees_done_right_i_hope.php)**:

Listing 1: instance declaration for Node

```
instance Reduce Node where
  reducer (-<) (Node2 a b) z = a -< (b -< z)
  reducer (-<) (Node3 a b c) z = a -< (b -< (c -< z))
  reducer (>-) (Node2 b a) = (z >- b) >- a
  reducer (>-) (Node3 c b a) = ((z >- c) >- b) >- a
```

Listing 2: instance declaration for FingerTree

```
instance Reduce FingerTree where
  reducer (-<) Empty zero = zero
  reducer (-<) (Single x) zero = x -< zero
  reducer (-<) Deep left mid right zero = left -<' (mid -<'' (right -<' zero))
    where (-<') = reducer (-<)
          (-<'') = reducer (reducer (-<))
  reducel (>-) zero Empty = zero
  reducel (>-) zero (Single x) = zero >- x
  reducel (>-) zero (Deep left mid right) = ((zero >-' left) >-'' mid) >-' right
    where (>-') = reducel (>-)
          (>-'') = reducel (reducel (>-))
```

listing 3: data types

```
data Node s = Node2 s s | Node3 s s s

data FingerTree a = Empty
  |  Single a
  | Deep (Digit a) (FingerTree (Node a)) (Digit a)

data Digit a = [ a ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that `reduce` is a common alternate name for a "fold" function, I'd guess that it's something similar to [the `Foldable` type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.4.1.0/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable). The instance definitions seem to make sense as such, as well.

The `Foldable` class can be defined using just `foldr`, which has the type signature `foldr :: (Foldable t) => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`, whereas the `reducer` in that code appears to be `reducer :: (Reduce t) => (a -> b -> b) -> t a -> b -> b`. Other than a different argument order, it should work the same.

Note that the operators are just arguments to the function--you could replace them all with `f` or another similarly generic identifier. Using an operator as the name of a binary function argument is... a slightly unusual choice, but it does emphasize some aspects of the structure of the fold, I guess.

Answer (score 6):

It's defined in the paper linked in the article: [Finger Trees: A Simple General-purpose Data Structure](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.html).

```
class Reduce f where
  reducer :: (a -> b -> b) -> (f a -> b -> b)
  reducel :: (b -> a -> b) -> (b -> f a -> b)
```