# Why aren't FingerTrees used enough to have a stable implementation?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, finger-tree

A while ago, I ran across [an article on FingerTrees](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2010/04/finger_trees_done_right_i_hope.php) (See Also [an accompanying Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450448/finding-the-missing-reduce-typeclass-from-finger-tree-article)) and filed the idea away.  I have finally found a reason to make use of them.

My problem is that the [Data.FingerTree package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fingertree-0.0.1.0) seems to have a little bit rot around the edges.  Moreover, [Data.Sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html) in the Containers package which makes use of the data structure [re-implements](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/src/Data-Sequence.html#line-259) a (possibly better) version, but doesn't export it.

As theoretically useful as this structure seems to be, it doesn't seem to get a lot of actual use or attention.  Have people found that FingerTrees are not useful as a practical matter, or is this a case not enough attention?

---

**further explanation**:

I'm interested in building a data structure holding text that has good concatenation properties. Think about building an HTML document from assorted fragments. Most pre-built solutions use bytestrings, but I really want something that deals with Unicode text properly. My plan at the moment is to layer Data.Text fragments into a FingerTree.

I would also like to borrow the trick from Data.Vector of taking slices without copying using (offset,length) manipulation.  Data.Text.Text has this built in to the data type, but only uses it for efficient uncons and unsnoc opperations.  In FingerTree this information could very easily becomes the `v` or annotation of the tree.

Comment: Why not use Data.Text.Lazy.Text?

Comment: Most people don't need to interface with the finger tree structure itself; they only need what they get from `Data.Sequence`.  Very few people actually encounter a case where they need to use the data structure directly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer your question about finger trees in particular, I think the problem is that they have relatively high constant costs compared to arrays, and are more complex than other ways of achieving efficient concatenation.  A Builder has a more efficient interface for just appending chunks, and they're usually readily available (see the links in @informatikr's answer).  Suppose that `Data.Text.Lazy` is implemented with a linked list of chunks, and you're creating a `Data.Text.Lazy` from a builder.  Unless you have a lot of chunks (probably more than 50), or are accessing data near the end of the list repeatedly, the high constant cost of a finger tree probably isn't worth it.

The `Data.Sequence` implementation is specialized for performance reasons, and isn't as general as the full interface provided by the `fingertree` package.  That's why it isn't exported; it's not really possible to use it for anything other than a `Sequence`.

I also suspect that many programmers are at a loss as to how to actually use the monoidal annotation, as it's behind a fairly significant abstraction barrier.  So many people wouldn't use it because they don't see how it can be useful compared to other data types.

I didn't really get it until I read Chung-chieh Shan's blog series on [word numbers](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/WordNumbers1/) ([part2](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/WordNumbers2/), [part3](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/WordNumbers3/), [part4](http://conway.rutgers.edu/~ccshan/wiki/blog/posts/WordNumbers4/)).  That's proof that the idea can definitely be used in practical code.

In your case, if you need to both inspect partial results and have efficient appends, using a fingertree may be better than a builder.  Depending on the builder's implementation, you may end up doing a lot of repeated work as you convert to `Text`, add more stuff to the builder, convert to `Text` again, etc.  It would depend on your usage pattern though.

You might be interested in my [splaytree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/splaytree) package, which provides splay trees with monoidal annotations, and several different structures build upon them.  Other than the splay tree itself, the `Set` and `RangeSet` modules have more-or-less complete API's, the `Sequence` module is mostly a skeleton I used for testing.  It's not a "batteries included" solution to what you're looking for (again, @informatikr's answer provides those), but if you want to experiment with monoidal annotations it may be more useful than `Data.FingerTree`.  Be aware that a splay tree can get unbalanced if you traverse all the elements in sequence (or continually snoc onto the end, or similar), but if appends and lookups are interleaved performance can be excellent.

Comment: John - your splaytree package looks very interesting. Would you be able to document the asymptotic complexity of the functions - looking at it now, I have no idea how its asymptotics compare to fingertree's.

Comment: @reinerp: it's a bit difficult to do so for splay trees, but you're right I should do it.  Any single operation of `lookup`, `insert`, `delete`, will have an amortized-time cost O(log n), with a worst-case of O(n).  However, the expected complexity for a sequence of operations can be better, see Sleator & Tarjan's paper "Self-Adjusting Binary Search Trees" for a discussion of that.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to John Lato's answer, I'll add some specific details about the performance of finger trees, since I spent some time looking at that in the past.

The broad summary is:

- `Data.Sequence` has great constant factors and asymptotics: it is almost as fast as `[]` when accessing the front of the list (where both data structures have O(1) asymptotics), and much faster elsewhere in the list (where `Data.Sequence`'s  logarithmic asymptotics trounce `[]`'s linear asymptotics).
- `Data.FingerTree` has the same asymptotics as `Data.Sequence`, but is about an order of magnitude slower.

Just like lists, finger trees have high per-element memory overheads, so they should be combined with chunking for better memory and cache use. Indeed, a few packages do this ([yi](https://github.com/yi-editor/yi/blob/master/yi/src/library/Data/Rope.hs#L73), [trifecta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta), [rope](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rope)). If `Data.FingerTree` could be brought close to `Data.Sequence` in performance, I would hope to see a `Data.Text.Sequence` type, which implemented a finger tree of `Data.Text` values. Such a type would lose the streaming behaviour of `Data.Text.Lazy`, but benefit from improved random access and concatenation performance. (Similarly, I would want to see `Data.ByteString.Sequence` and `Data.Vector.Sequence`.)

The obstacle to implementing these now is that no **efficient** and **generic** implementation of finger trees exists (see below where I discuss this further). To produce efficient implementations of `Data.Text.Sequence` one would have to completely reimplement finger trees, specialised to `Text` - just as `Data.Text.Lazy` completely reimplements lists, specialised to `Text`. Unfortunately, finger trees are much more complex than lists (especially [concatenation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fingertree/0.0.1.0/doc/html/src/Data-FingerTree.html#line-414)!), so this is a considerable amount of work.

So as I see it the answer is:

- specialised finger trees are great, but a lot of work to implement
- chunked finger trees (e.g. `Data.Text.Sequence`) *would be* great, but at present the poor performance of `Data.FingerTree` means they are not a viable alternative to chunked lists in the common case
- builders and chunked lists achieve many of the benefits of chunked finger trees, and so they suffice for the common case
- in the *uncommon* case where builders and chunked lists don't suffice, we grit our teeth and put up with the poor constant factors of chunked finger trees (e.g. in yi and trifecta).

## Obstacles to an efficient and generic finger tree

Much of the performance gap between `Data.Sequence` and `Data.FingerTree` is due to two optimisations in `Data.Sequence`:

- The measure type is specialised to `Int`, so measure manipulations will compile down to efficient integer arithmetic rather
- [The measure type is unpacked into the `Deep` constructor](https://github.com/haskell/containers/blob/master/Data/Sequence.hs#L274), which saves pointer dereferences in the inner loops of the tree operations.

It is possible to apply these optimisations in the general case of `Data.FingerTree` by using [data families for generic unpacking](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/self-optimizing-data-structures-using-types-to-make-lists-faster/) and by exploiting GHC's inliner and specialiser - see my [fingertree-unboxed package](https://github.com/reinerp/fingertree-unboxed), which brings generic finger tree performance almost up to that of `Data.Sequence`. Unfortunately, these techniques have some significant problems:

- [data families for generic unpacking is unpleasant for the user](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2010-August/019052.html), because they have to define lots of instances. There is no clear solution to this problem.
- finger trees use polymorphic recursion, which GHC's specialiser doesn't handle well ([1](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5326), [2](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5298)). This means that, to get sufficient specialisation on the measure type, we need lots of `INLINE` pragmas, which causes GHC to generate huge amounts of code.

Due to these problems, I never released the package on Hackage.

Comment: I know this is nearly six years later, but in GHC 8.2, Edward Yang implemented backpack, which, roughly speaking, provides a way to specialize whole modules, including unpacking polymorphic data. No one has written a fingerprint as an indefinite backpack module yet, but this would address the problems cited in this answer.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I'm wrong about backpack being useful here: https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8a5w1n/new_package_unpackedcontainers/dwwyzxe/

Answer (score 7):

Ignoring your Finger Tree question and only responding to your further explanation: did you look into [Data.Text.Lazy.Builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.2/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html) or, specifically for building HTML, [blaze-html](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-html)?

Both allow fast concatenation. For slicing, if that is important for solving your problem, they might not have ideal performance.

Comment: So, let me ask a follow-up: Data.Text.Lazy.Builder's performance looks like it is based in a well crafted foldr/build rewrite rule (see line ~290). My project involves creating a scripting DLS that churns out text from templates (not necessary HTML though that is a prime use case).  I believe that sense the choice of what to concatenate/slice and when happens at runtime that the compile time optimization are ineffective in this case. Would you agree?

Comment: No, that's not true. The rewrite rule you're looking at is just there to eliminate some array bounds checks, and doesn't affect asymptotic performance. Builders use a technique very similar to difference lists (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_list) to guarantee O(1) concatenation, without requiring any compile-time optimisations to apply.