# Is there a aggregation version of Sequences exists already?

Tags: haskell, data-structures

Consider we have a sequence of monoid elements, `Data.Sequence` is great for inserting, changing elements in certain positions.

I'm concerned with the following query, `sum i j sequence`, which returns the `mconcat` of all elements from position `i` to `j`. This can be done with by using a `FingerTree` with measure contain both the index and the `mconcat` result in O(log n) time.

Is there already a implementation of this in some Haskell library? Or do I have to implement `Data.Sequence` again with this ability with `Data.FingerTree`? (`Sequence` expose too little internal structure to do this effectively.)

Comment: See [this answer for an idea of why Data.Sequence doesn't expose this functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11154294/9859).