# What is the Store comonad?

Tags: haskell, comonad

Having some idea of [what the Comonad typeclass is in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428554/what-is-the-comonad-typeclass-in-haskell), I've heard about the Store comonad. But looking at [Control.Comonad.Store.Lazy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonads-fd/2.0.1/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Store-Lazy.html), I don't really get it. What does it mean? What is it for? I've heard that Store = CoState, the dual of the State Monad. What does that mean?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's much easier if you look at the definition of [StoreT itself](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/comonad-transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Comonad-Trans-Store.html#t%3aStoreT).

You can think of it as a "place" in a larger structure. For instance, a [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-lens/latest/doc/html/Data-Lens-Common.html#t%3aLens) is just `a -> Store b a`; you get the value of the *b* field, and a function `b -> a` to put a new value back into the larger context.

Considering it in its simplified, non-transformer form:

```hs
data Store s a = Store (s -> a) s

instance Functor (Store s) where
  fmap f (Store g s) = Store (f . g) s

instance Extend (Store s) where
  duplicate (Store f s) = Store (Store f) s

instance Comonad (Store s) where
  extract (Store f s) = f s
```

i.e. `duplicate` changes the `s -> a` into an `s -> Store s a` that just returns the "updated" place after replacing the value, and `extract` restores the original *a* by placing the value back into the larger structure.

As far as its relation to State goes, you could look at it like this:

```hs
type State s a = s -> (a, s)
type Store s a = (s -> a, s)
```

Comment: Just to expand on the connection between State and Store, all monads arise from a composition of adjoint functors. It's commonly known that the functors `(r -> _)` (a.k.a. Reader) and `(_, r)` (flipped works too, but doesn't fit the usual presentation of State in Haskell, and can't be a Functor instance in Haskell) are adjoint, and if you compose them one way (`s -> (_ , s)`) you'll get a monad, and if you compose them the other way (`(s -> _, s)`) you'll get a comonad.

Comment: @copumpkin: It's `(_, r)` that can't be a Functor, isn't it? `(r, _)` is just `instance Functor ((,) r)`.

Comment: That's a dead link.  The modules named `.Lazy`, `.Strict`, and `.Memo` were removed in version 2.1 for no apparent reason.

Comment: @JoeyAdams I've taken the liberty of fixing the broken link. I think I've heard edwardk give some reason about why he removed `.Strict` modules, but I forget why.

Comment: @DanBurton: Thanks for updating the link.  The answer he gave is: "fmap f undefined = WriterT (Identity (undefined, undefined)) ... it makes up a lot of structure from nothing"

Answer (score 55):

Given the following definition of store,

```
data Store s a = Store { peek :: s -> a, pos :: s }
```

I like to think of a `Store` as a big warehouse filled with values of type `a`.  Each value of type `a` is slotted into a position labeled by an index value of type `s`.  Finally there is a forklift parked at position `pos`.  The forklift can be used to `extract` a value of type `a` from the store by pulling the value out from where it is parked.  You can use `seek` to move the forklift to a new absolute position or use `seeks` to move the forklift to a new relative location.  To update all values of the store use `fmap`.  Finally `extend f` is similar to `fmap` except instead of `f :: a -> a'` we have `f :: Store s a -> a'` which lets the update function not only have access to the value being updated but also gives access to the value's position and access to the values of everything else in the store.  In other words, `extend` uses the value plus its surrounding context to perform the update.

A more computery analogy would be to think of a `Store` as a big platter of a hard disk with values stored at various positions, plus a head parked at a particular position.