# Does the chain function in underscore.js create a monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, underscore.js, comonad

In [the `chain` documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining) you find:

> Calling `chain` on a wrapped object will cause all future method calls
>   to return wrapped objects as well. When you've finished the
>   computation, use `value` to retrieve the final value.

So does the [`chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain) function create a monad?

Comment: I've tagged this haskell, because haskellers might have something to say on this topic.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

No, not a monad, but a comonad! It turns a function that takes a wrapped object and returns a normal value into a function that both takes and returns a wrapped object. As a Haskell type signature that would be:

```
(Wrapped a -> b) -> (Wrapped a -> Wrapped b)
```

The type signature of `value` is:

```
Wrapped a -> a
```

These are precisely what you need for a comonad. The first function is usually called `extend` and the second `extract`.

You can think of a comonad as a value with some extra context. And that is of course exactly what `chain` does.

See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428554/what-is-the-comonad-typeclass-in-haskell) for more about comonads.

Comment: I like this answer;  I think it would be more immediately apparent what you mean if you were to explain the mapping of underscore object methods onto types.  If I understand correctly, methods are normally `Wrapped a -> b`s but that `chain` returns an object whose methods (except `value`) are all `Wrapped a -> Wrapped b`s.  I know a little Haskell, but the question was not originally tagged Haskell so explanations of how your answer maps to the JS library might be helpful.

Comment: I have a similar comment here: I understand chain as a function that takes a value and returns a wrapped object so `chain:: a => Wrapped a`, and that makes it look like a monadic `return` or `unit`. Methods used on `Wrapped` are such that `method:: Wrapped a -> (a -> b) -> Wrapped b`. For instance, map or reduce (`_ -> f -> reduce(_,  f, seed)`). That looks like standard `method _ f = fmap f _` with a different f for each method. Except the `value` method which is `:: Wrapped a -> a` and indeed looks like a comonadic `extract`. There could be a comonad involved but it is not easily visible.