# Comonad example in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, comonad

What is Comonad, if it's possible describe in Scala syntax. 
I found [scalaz](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/Comonad.scala.html) library implementation, but it's not clear where it can be useful.

Comment: See also: [What is the Comonad typeclass in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428554/what-is-the-comonad-typeclass-in-haskell). Scalaz generally tries to make things as Haskell-ish as possible, so those blog posts may help.

Comment: Also see also: recent reddit post at /r/haskell [A Notation for Comonads](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/v6ik6/a_notation_for_comonads_orchard_mycroft_pdf/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, monads allow you to add values to them, change them based on a computation from a non-monad to a monad. Comonads allow you to extract values from them, and change them based on a computation from a comonad to a non-comonad.

The natural intuition is that they'll usually appear where you have a CM[A] and want to extract A.

See [this](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/strong-functional-programming.html) very interesting post that touches on comonads a bit casually, but, to me at least, making them very clear.

Comment: "The natural intuition is that they'll usually appear where you have a CM[A] and want to extract A." That's `Copointed`/`Copure`. Add to it `extract` (`W[A] => (W[A] => B) => W[B]`) or `cojoin` (`W[A] => W[W[A]]`), and you get `Comonad`.

Comment: @missingfaktor I am not defining them -- I assume Stas has seen the definition already. I am saying comonads will usually be found in situations like this.

Answer (score 7):

What follows is a literal translation of code from [this](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/12/evaluating-cellular-automata-is.html) blog post.

```
case class U[X](left: Stream[X], center: X, right: Stream[X]) {
  def shiftRight = this match {
    case U(a, b, c #:: cs) => U(b #:: a, c, cs)
  }

  def shiftLeft = this match {
    case U(a #:: as, b, c) => U(as, a, b #:: c)
  }
}

// Not necessary, as Comonad also has fmap.
/*
implicit object uFunctor extends Functor[U] {
  def fmap[A, B](x: U[A], f: A => B): U[B] = U(x.left.map(f), f(x.center), x.right.map(f))
}
*/

implicit object uComonad extends Comonad[U] {
  def copure[A](u: U[A]): A = u.center
  def cojoin[A](a: U[A]): U[U[A]] = U(Stream.iterate(a)(_.shiftLeft).tail, a, Stream.iterate(a)(_.shiftRight).tail)
  def fmap[A, B](x: U[A], f: A => B): U[B] = U(x.left.map(f), x.center |> f, x.right.map(f))
}

def rule(u: U[Boolean]) = u match {
  case U(a #:: _, b, c #:: _) => !(a && b && !c || (a == b))
}

def shift[A](i: Int, u: U[A]) = {
  Stream.iterate(u)(x => if (i < 0) x.shiftLeft else x.shiftRight).apply(i.abs)
}

def half[A](u: U[A]) = u match {
  case U(_, b, c) => Stream(b) ++ c
}

def toList[A](i: Int, j: Int, u: U[A]) = half(shift(i, u)).take(j - i)

val u = U(Stream continually false, true, Stream continually false)

val s = Stream.iterate(u)(_ =>> rule)

val s0 = s.map(r => toList(-20, 20, r).map(x => if(x) '#' else ' '))

val s1 = s.map(r => toList(-20, 20, r).map(x => if(x) '#' else ' ').mkString("|")).take(20).force.mkString("\n")

println(s1)
```

Output:

```
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| |#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#|#|#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| | | |#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#| | |#|#| | | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| |#| |#| |#| | | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#| | | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| | | | | | | |#| | | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#| | | | | | |#|#| | | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| |#| | | | | |#| |#| | | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#|#|#| | | | |#|#|#|#| | | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| | | |#| | | |#| | | |#| | | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#| | |#|#| | |#|#| | |#|#| | | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| |#| |#| |#| |#| |#| |#| |#| | | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#|#| | | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| | |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#| | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#| |
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| |#| | | | | | | | | | | | | |#| |#|
 | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#|#|#| | | | | | | | | | | | |#|#|#|#
```

Comment: Import for `Comonad` is missing. `=>>` and `|>` are not defined too.

Comment: @EnverOsmanov, this post is from a time when I did not realise the importance of including imports in code snippets. :-) Anyway, Scalaz has changed hugely since, and the packages have seen multiple reorganisation rounds. I would appreciate it if you could update this post as per new Scalaz (or Cats, if that's your poison).

Answer (score 1):

The [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) provides a [`ComonadStore`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/ComonadStore.scala) which extends the property of `Comonad`. It is defined like this:

```scala
trait ComonadStore[F[_], S] extends Comonad[F] { self =>

  def pos[A](w: F[A]): S
  def peek[A](s: S, w: F[A]): A

  def peeks[A](s: S => S, w: F[A]): A =
    peek(s(pos(w)), w)

  def seek[A](s: S, w: F[A]): F[A] =
    peek(s, cojoin(w))

  def seeks[A](s: S => S, w: F[A]): F[A] =
    peeks(s, cojoin(w))

  def experiment[G[_], A](s: S => G[S], w: F[A])(implicit FG: Functor[G]): G[A] =
    FG.map(s(pos(w)))(peek(_, w))

}
```

And a [`Store`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/7e64f43872fc944b54a63e4262acaea2248f50c8/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/package.scala#L197)( which is analogous to `(S => A, S)`) has an instance of `Comonad`. You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888056/what-is-store-in-scalaz) that explains what it is more specifically.

You also have the `Coreader` and `Cowriter` `Comonads` that are the dual of the `Reader` and `Writer` `Monads`, here is an excellent [blog](http://blog.higher-order.com/blog/2015/06/23/a-scala-comonad-tutorial/) post that talks about it in Scala.