# What benefits do I get from creating an instance of Comonad

Tags: haskell, comonad

In my application, I'm trying to implement an animation system. In this system, animations are represented as a cyclic list of frames:

```
data CyclicList a = CL a [a]
```

We can (inefficiently) advance the animation as follows:

```
advance :: CyclicList a -> CyclicList a
advance (CL x []) = CL x []
advance (CL x (z:zs)) = CL z (zs ++ [x])
```

Now, I'm pretty sure that this data type is a comonad:

```
instance Functor CyclicList where
  fmap f (CL x xs) = CL (f x) (map f xs)

cyclicFromList :: [a] -> CyclicList a
cyclicFromList [] = error "Cyclic list must have one element!"
cyclicFromList (x:xs) = CL x xs

cyclicLength :: CyclicList a -> Int
cyclicLength (CL _ xs) = length xs + 1

listCycles :: CyclicList a -> [CyclicList a]
listCycles cl = let
  helper 0 _ = []
  helper n cl' = cl' : (helper (n-1) $ advance cl')
 in helper (cyclicLength cl) cl

instance Comonad CyclicList where
  extract (CL x _) = x
  duplicate = cyclicFromList . listCycles
```

The question I have is: what kind of benefits do I get (if any) from using the comonad instance?

Comment: You'll be able to make use of any functions that are parametrized to work on arbitrary comonads.  I can't point to any right now, but I'm sure there are some that exist.

Comment: [What is the comonad typeclass in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428554/what-is-the-comonad-typeclass-in-haskell?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of providing a type class or implementing an interface is that code, written to use that typeclass or interface, can use your code without any modifications.

What programs can be written in terms of `Comonad`? A `Comonad` provides a way to both inspect the value at the current location (without observing its neighbors) using `extract` and a way to observe the neighborhood of every location with `duplicate` or `extend`. Without any additional functions, this isn't terribly useful. However, if we also require other functions along with the `Comonad` instance, we can write programs that depend on both local data and data from elsewhere. For example, if we require functions that allow us to change location, such as your `advance`, we can write programs that depend only on the local structure of the data, not on the data structure itself.

For a concrete example, consider a cellular automata program written in terms of `Comonad` and the following `Bidirectional` class:

```
class Bidirectional c where
    forward  :: c a -> Maybe (c a)
    backward :: c a -> Maybe (c a)
```

The program could use this, together with `Comonad`, to `extract` data stored in a cell and explore the cells `forward` and `backward` of the current cell. It can use `duplicate` to capture the neighborhood of each cell and `fmap` to inspect that neighborhood. This combination of `fmap f . duplicate` is `extract f`.

Here is such a program. `rule'` is only interesting to the example; it implements cellular automata rules on neighborhood with just the left and right values. `rule` extracts data from the neighborhood, given the class, and runs the rule on each neighborhood. `slice` pulls out even larger neighborhoods so that we can display them easily. `simulate` runs the simulation, displaying these larger neighborhoods for each generation.

```
rule' :: Word8 -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool -> Bool
rule' x l m r = testBit x ((if l then 4 else 0) .|. (if m then 2 else 0) .|. (if r then 1 else 0))

rule :: (Comonad w, Bidirectional w) => Word8 -> w Bool -> w Bool
rule x = extend go
    where
        go w = rule' x (maybe False extract . backward $ w) (extract w) (maybe False extract . forward $ w)

slice :: (Comonad w, Bidirectional w) => Int -> Int -> a -> w a -> [a]
slice l r a w = sliceL l w (extract w : sliceR r w)
    where
        sliceR r w | r > 0 = case (forward w) of
            Nothing -> take r (repeat a)
            Just w' -> extract w' : sliceR (r-1) w'
        sliceR _ _ = []
        sliceL l w r | l > 0 = case (backward w) of
            Nothing -> take l (repeat a) ++ r
            Just w' -> sliceL (l-1) w' (extract w':r)
        sliceL _ _ r = r

simulate :: (Comonad w, Bidirectional w) => (w Bool -> w Bool) -> Int -> Int -> Int -> w Bool -> IO ()
simulate f l r x w = mapM_ putStrLn . map (map (\x -> if x then '1' else '0') . slice l r False) . take x . iterate f $ w
```

This program might have been intended to work with the following `Bidirectional` `Comonad`, a `Zipper` on a list.

```
data Zipper a = Zipper {
    heads :: [a],
    here  :: a,
    tail  :: [a]
} deriving Functor

instance Bidirectional Zipper where
    forward (Zipper _ _ []    ) = Nothing
    forward (Zipper l h (r:rs)) = Just $ Zipper (h:l) r rs
    backward (Zipper []     _ _) = Nothing
    backward (Zipper (l:ls) h r) = Just $ Zipper ls l (h:r)

instance Comonad Zipper where
    extract = here
    duplicate (Zipper l h r) = Zipper (goL (h:r) l) (Zipper l h r) (goR (h:l) r)
        where
            goL r []    = []
            goL r (h:l) = Zipper l h r : goL (h:r) l
            goR l []    = []
            goR l (h:r) = Zipper l h r : goR (h:l) r
```

But will also work with a `CyclicList` `Bidirectional` `Comonad`.

```
data CyclicList a = CL a (Seq a)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

instance Bidirectional CyclicList where
    forward (CL x xs) = Just $ case viewl xs of
        EmptyL    -> CL x xs
        x' :< xs' -> CL x' (xs' |> x)
    backward (CL x xs) = Just $ case viewr xs of
        EmptyR    -> CL x xs
        xs' :> x' -> CL x' (x <| xs')

instance Comonad CyclicList where
    extract   (CL x _) = x
    duplicate (CL x xs) = CL (CL x xs) (go (singleton x) xs)
        where
            go old new = case viewl new of
                EmptyL -> empty
                x' :< xs' -> CL x' (xs' >< old) <| go (old |> x') xs'
```

We can reuse `simulate` with either data structure. The `CyclicList` has a more interesting output, because, instead of bumping into a wall, it wraps back around to interact with itself.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Comonad
import Data.Sequence hiding (take)
import Data.Bits
import Data.Word

main = do
    putStrLn "10 + 1 + 10 Zipper"
    simulate (rule 110) 10 10 30 $ Zipper (take 10 . repeat $ False) True (take 10 . repeat $ False)
    putStrLn "10 + 1 + 10 Cyclic"
    simulate (rule 110) 10 10 30 $ CL True (fromList (take 20 . repeat $ False))
```