# Recursion scheme in Haskell for repeatedly breaking datatypes into "head" and "tail" and yielding a structure of results

Tags: haskell, recursion

In Haskell, I recently found the following function useful:

```
listCase :: (a -> [a] -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
listCase f [] = []
listCase f (x:xs) = f x xs : listCase f xs
```

I used it to generate sliding windows of size 3 from a list, like this:

```
*Main> listCase (\_ -> take 3) [1..5]
[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5],[]]
```

Is there a more general recursion scheme which captures this pattern? More specifically, that allows you to generate a some structure of results by repeatedly breaking data into a "head" and "tail"?

Comment: Theoretically, `foldr` is the most general list eliminator, but one hardly wants to use it in all cases. In your example, I'd write `map foo (tails list)` and do the splitting by hand, or even `[ f x xs | (x:xs) <- tails list ]` which handles the empty tail case more gracefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a special case of a (jargon here but it can help with googling) paramorphism, a generalisation of [primitive recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) to all initial algebras.

### Reimplementing ListCase

Let's have a look at how to reimplement your function using such a combinator. First we define the notion of paramorphism: a recursion principle where not only the result of the recursive call is available but also the entire substructure this call was performed on:

The type of `paraList` tells me that in the `(:)` case, I will have access to the head, the tail and the value of the recursive call on the tail and that I need to provide a value for the base case.

```
module ListCase where

paraList :: (a -> [a] -> b -> b) -- cons
            -> b                 -- nil
            -> [a] -> b          -- resulting function on lists
paraList c n []       = n
paraList c n (x : xs) = c x xs $ paraList c n xs
```

We can now give an alternative definition of `listCase`:

```
listCase' :: (a -> [a] -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
listCase' c = paraList (\ x xs tl -> c x xs : tl) []
```

### Considering the general case

In the general case, we are interested in building a definition of paramorphism for all data structures defined as the fixpoint of a (strictly positive) functor. We use the traditional fixpoint operator:

```
newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }
```

This builds an inductive structure layer by layer. The layers have an `f` shape which maybe better grasped by recalling the definition of `List` using this formalism. A layer is either `Nothing` (we're done!) or `Just (head, tail)`:

```
newtype ListF a as = ListF { unListF :: Maybe (a, as) }
type List a = Fix (ListF a)

nil :: List a
nil = Fix $ ListF $ Nothing

cons :: a -> List a -> List a
cons = curry $ Fix . ListF .Just
```

Now that we have this general framework, we can define para generically for all `Fix f` where `f` is a functor:

```
para :: Functor f => (f (Fix f, b) -> b) -> Fix f -> b
para alg = alg . fmap (\ rec -> (rec, para alg rec)) . unFix
```

Of course, `ListF a` is a functor. Meaning we could use `para` to reimplement `paraList` and `listCase`.

```
instance Functor (ListF a) where fmap f = ListF . fmap (fmap f) . unListF

paraList' :: (a -> List a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
paraList' c n = para $ maybe n (\ (a, (as, b)) -> c a as b) . unListF

listCase'' :: (a -> List a -> b) -> List a -> List b
listCase'' c = paraList' (\ x xs tl -> cons (c x xs) tl) nil
```

You can implement a simple bijection `toList`, `fromList` to test it if you want. I could not be bothered to reimplement `take` so it's pretty ugly:

```
toList :: [a] -> List a
toList = foldr cons nil

fromList :: List a -> [a]
fromList = paraList' (\ x _ tl -> x : tl) []

*ListCase> fmap fromList . fromList . listCase'' (\ _ as -> toList $ take 3 $ fromList as). toList $ [1..5]
[[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5],[]]
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are asking for is a **comonad**. This may sound scarier than *monad*, but is a simpler concept (YMMV).

Comonads are Functors with additional structure:

```
class Functor w => Comonad w where
    extract :: w a -> a
    duplicate :: w a -> w (w a)
    extend :: (w a -> b) -> w a -> w b
```

(`extend`and `duplicate` can be defined in terms of each other)
and laws similar to the monad laws:

```
duplicate . extract = id
duplicate . fmap extract = id
duplicate . duplicate = fmap duplicate . duplicate
```

Specifically, the signature `(a -> [a] -> b)` takes non-empty Lists of type `a`. The usual type `[a]` is not an instance of a comonad, but the non-empty lists are:

```
data NE a = T a | a :. NE a deriving Functor

instance Comonad NE where
   extract (T x) = x
   extract (x :. _) = x
   duplicate z@(T _) = T z
   duplicate z@(_ :. xs) = z :. duplicate xs
```

The comonad laws allow only this instance for non-empty lists (actually a second one).

Your function then becomes

```
extend (take 3 . drop 1 . toList)
```

Where `toList :: NE a -> [a]` is obvious.
This is worse than the original, but extend can be written as `=>>` which is simpler if applied repeatedly.

For further information, you may start at [What is the Comonad typeclass in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8428554/412549).

Comment: Well.  With the exception that `[]` can't be an instance of `Comonad`. But Edward Kmett has a [package including comonad-without-extract](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.0.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Extend.html).